# LoadError: Unable to autoload constant (Rails + Sidekiq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, sidekiq

In my development environement I am getting this error :

```
WARN: LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Alerts::FailedReportWorker, expected /my-path/app/workers/alerts/failed_report_worker.rb to define it.
```

I have these workers in my schedule.yml file :

```
alert_sla_worker:
  cron: "*/1 * * * *"
  class: "Alerts::SlaWorker"
alert_failed_export_worker:
  cron: "*/1 * * * *"
  class: "Alerts::FailedExportWorker"
alert_failed_report_worker:
  cron: "*/1 * * * *"
  class: "Alerts::FailedReportWorker"
alert_failed_extractor_worker:
  cron: "*/1 * * * *"
  class: "Alerts::FailedExtractorWorker"
```

My folder structure looks like this :

```
workers
 alerts(folder)
  failed_export_worker.rb
  failed_extractor_worker.rb
  failed_report_worker.rb
  sla_worker.rb
```

And failed_report_worker.rb :

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Alerts
  class FailedReportWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    sidekiq_options queue: :default, retry: 0

    def perform
        ...
    end
  end
end
```

How can I fix this issue ? I'm not sure what I'm missing!

Comment: how does `failed_report_worker.rb` look like?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev I've edited the original post :)

Comment: Weird that it complains only about that worker. Can you try to restart? Can you double-triple check you don’t have typo in file name or classname?

Comment: @Olkin I've already done that :( . My coworkers pulled the code and they have the same issue.  Could it be a problem with my autoload configuration ? The weirdest thing is that it doesn't happen every time the worker starts, only like 1 time out of 5....

Comment: Test 
    `config.autoload_paths += Dir[config.root.join('app', 'workers', '**/*.rb')]`

Comment: where is `workers` folder located? Right under `app`?

Comment: @Olkin Yep, app > workers > alerts > files.rb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be issue with autoloading... I've faced this type of issue recently.
Try to do this:
add under `workers` directory a file named `alerts.rb` with following code inside:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Alerts; end
```

It would be great if it helps

Comment: Hey ! It seems like it solved my problem, it's really weird .. I will wait a little to see if the error appears again. And if not I will mark your answer as the solution. Thanks a lot !

Comment: This requirement seems to be enforced as of Rails 5.2.0. Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601195/2769838) for more details